# Chart.js V2.1.4 does working, with backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, chart.js

I want to use a upgraded version of Chart.js v2.1.4 with Backbone View(working fine with v1.0.2) as because of additional features.But it not working with upgraded version v 2.1.4.

Code snippet are:

```js
define([
   'underscore', 
   'jquery',   
   'backbone',
   'Chart',
   'text!templates/dashboard/graph-view-template.html'
], function(_, $, Backbone, Chart, GraphViewTemplate) {

    var GraphView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: GraphViewTemplate,
      events: {
      },

      elements: {
      },

      initialize: function(options){
        this.options = options;
      },

      render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        this.renderTempGraph();
        return this;
      },

      renderTempGraph: function(){
        var ctx = this.$el.find("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
      }
  return GraphView;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

after render, canvas element properties look like as

```html
<iframe class="chartjs-hidden-iframe" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
</iframe>

<canvas id="myChart" width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please explain how it is not working. What are you expecting that does not happen? Any error messages? Any other unexpected results?

Comment: Yeah its not plotting the graphs, There has not been displaying on my page. On inspecting the <canvas> element , there is blank <iframe> has attached as sibling and the canvas properties(height and width) has overridden.

Comment: You still have not said whether there were any error messages. Did you check the console? This is all information you need to add to your question. (Even if there are no error message, you must say so explicitly: like "There are no error messages on the console.")

Comment: Yeah, there is no error has thrown, I had also debugged the library, i have been noticed the height and width of canvas is being overridden with 0.There might be  libraries  functions expecting something else.